# SQL Full outer join exclusion, select non existing row

Tags: sql, join, left-join, outer-join

I have 3 tables:

```
section
id
name

permission
id
section_id
name

exclusion_permission
permission_id
```

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    p.id AS permission_id,
    p.name AS permission_name,
    s.id AS section_id,
    s.name AS section_name
FROM
    section s

LEFT OUTER JOIN
    permission p
ON
    p.section_id = s.id

LEFT OUTER JOIN
    exclusion_permission lep
ON
    lep.permission_id = p.id

WHERE
    lep.permission_id IS NULL
```

The table data is:

```
section
id     name
1      admin
2      sales
3      moderator
4      intern

permission
id     section_id    name
1      1             root
2      2             sell
3      2             buy
4      3             edit_user
5      3             delete_user
```

The query will return

```
1, root, 1, admin
2, sell, 2, sales
3, buy, 2, sales
4, edit_user, 3, moderator
5, delete_user, 3, moderator
,, 4, intern
```

Now if I throw the following exclusion permissions into the mix:

```
exclusion_permission
permission_id
1
5
```

The query will return:

```
2, sell, 2, sales
3, buy, 2, sales
4, edit_user, 3, moderator
,, 4, intern
```

As you can see, the moderator section is still there because it has one more row associated with it. The admin section however is removed because the only permission it is associated with has been excluded. What I want to do is to have my query return the following:

```
,, 1, admin
2, sell, 2, sales
3, buy, 2, sales
4, edit_user, 3, moderator
,, 4, intern
```

So that if the section has no permissions, show the section. Also if a section has permissions which are all excluded, still show the section with no associated permission.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these records with `UNION`:

```
...
UNION
SELECT NULL,
       NULL,
       id,
       name
FROM section
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT section_id
                 FROM permission
                 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT permission_id
                                  FROM exclusion_permission))
```

([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88632/2))

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the joins, and only join `permission` if no `exclusion_permission` was found:

```
SELECT
    p.id AS permission_id,
    p.name AS permission_name,
    s.id AS section_id,
    s.name AS section_name
FROM
    section s
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    exclusion_permission lep
ON
    lep.permission_id = s.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    permission p
ON
    p.section_id = s.id
    AND lep.permission_id IS NULL
```

[Working example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/51d2b/1/0)

Comment: This does not give the desired result.